# Glimpse disappears on exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I have installed Glimpse in my MVC3 app. Enabled it and now I see Glimpse panel at the bottom of the page on sucesfull request. The problem is that I would like to debug binding exception and if exception appears(yellow screen) the Glimpse panel disappears. Is it possible to debug binding problems with Glimpse? The Glimpse page says that it is possible but do not provide any details how to do that on exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Glimpse is only configured to run on certain response codes (200, 301, 302)

Unfortunately, in the current version of Glimpse, this is not configurable and would require a code change.

The good news is, you have a few options:

1. Grab the source and add 500 to the list of status codes in the ResponseCodeValidator.cs file. (Note: This will get Glimpse to appear on your YSOD (Yellow Screen of Death), but depending on the exception and when it is thrown, Glimpse may not be of much value.)
2. Wait for the next version of Glimpse, in which we have already made the status code list configurable. In addition, we are working hard to have a better experience with Glimpse and YSOD's

Comment: What's the current status of Glimpse and YSOD's?  I recently pulled the latest version from Nuget, added to my app, configured the status codes yet it won't show up on YSOD's.